# How do I backup my wallet?

Tags: backup

Using bitcoin-qt, multibit, or any of the others, how do I backup and save my wallet in case I need to reinstall Windows?

Comment: Possibly related - http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/746/323

Answer (score 7):

### bitcoin-qt

- open the `File` menu
- click `Backup Wallet...`
- select a file to save the backup as

### MultiBit

From http://multibit.org/help_backupWalletUsingPrivateKeys.html:

> You can export your private keys from a MultiBit wallet into a file
>   (using the 'Tools | Export private keys' option) and, as long as you
>   do not manually create new receiving addresses, you can use the
>   private key file as a backup for the wallet.

### Armory

From http://bitcoinarmory.com/index.php/start-page/what-is-armory/features:

> Not only are the wallets determinstic, but there is a built-in dialog
>   for printing permanent copies of your wallet.  When you first create
>   your wallet, make sure your printer is on and click the “Paper Backup”
>   checkbox.

### Electrum

From http://electrum.org/:

> You do not need to perform regular backups, because your wallet can be
>   recovered from a secret phrase that you can memorize or write on
>   paper.