# What's the difference between all kinds of bitcoin addresses (Single, multisig, etc...) also compared to all bitcoin forks?

Tags: wallet, address, public-key, address-generation, multi-signature

Bitcoin addresses start with `1`. Multisig/Script addresses start with `3`. Other forks of bitcoin have single letters that are different at the beginning. Is this letter simply and only prepended to the address after calculating it from the public key, or is there more math to be done in certain cases?

Comment: please find here some reference with links inside: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses and step 4, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/48322. Also I draw a picture in my response to this thread: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/69315/how-are-compressed-pubkeys-generated/69366?noredirect=1#comment80625_69366. But I think it will be difficult to get the answer you are looking for - there are more than 1500 crypto currencies - maybe be a bit more specific what you are looking for?

Comment: @pebwindkraft Thanks for the answer. Well, come on. There's no 1500 bitcoin forks. Most of these 1500 are ethereum tokens. Let's talk about some like Dash, Litecoin, Vertcoin, Smartcash, Neblio, and a few others. All I see is that they have different prefixes. I'm wondering whether there's more to do there than prefixes.

Comment: @RutgerVersteegden I did mention examples in the last comment.